# How to make a symbolic vector into a pure function?

Tags: pure-function

As part of a set of functions to implement a steepest descent algorithm I created my own n dimensional gradient function.  It is defined as follows:

```
makeNfunc[func_, var_, n_] :=  Module[{}, ClearAll[var]; func @@ Evaluate[(var[#] & /@ Range[n])]]

GradN[func_, var_, n_] :=  Module[{}, ClearAll[var]; Array[D[makeNfunc[func, var, n], var[#]] &, n]]
```

The first command 'pipes in' n variables indexed as a sequence (if there's a better way to do this I am open to suggestions) to the function f. The module is so that I can run ClearAll so that "var" will just be a dummy sequence that can represent n variables. The reason I pipe in variables like this is so that I have variables for the D command to work with. I would prefer an alternative way of doing this that does not have to come up with contrived inputs to take the derivatives.

For a given input function the result of this GradN is an n dimensional vector with symbolic entries corresponding to the partial derivatives. I want to be able to evaluate this symbolic vector at multiple inputs and do numerical computations on the result. This can be achieved with a replacement rule like

```
/.var[#]->input[[#]]&/@Range[n]
```

where input is a list representing a point that I want to evaluate the gradient at. I would rather be able to get the gradient as a pure function, avoiding any contrived variable names and replacement rules for those variable names. I would prefer to use apply with the purefunction version of the gradient than a symbolic replacement rule using /.

Basically I don't want to need the makeNfunc command. I want to be able to take the gradient of an anonymous function of n variables and turn that gradient into a function that I can plug values into.

Comment: Are you wedded to your gradient function, or is a solution using other means acceptable?

Comment: I don't particularly care for my functions. Any implementation that avoids needing to name the variables is welcome.

Comment: OK, check below, if that's not what you had in mind let me know, I'll remove it...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per your comment, I *think* this fits the bill:

```
(* example pure fn w/ 3 arguments *)
f = Sin[#1]*Cos[#2] - Tan[#3]*#2 &

(* get the gradient as a pure function *)
gf = Evaluate[Grad[f[[-1]], Union[f[[Sequence @@ #]] & /@ Position[f, Slot[_]]]]] &

(* use it *)
gf

gf[0, 2, 3] // N

(*

{Cos[#1] Cos[#2],-Sin[#1] Sin[#2]-Tan[#3],-Sec[#3]^2 #2}&

{-0.416147,0.142547,-2.04064}

*)
```

And for named arguments using *Function*:

```
f = Function[{a, b, c}, Sin[a]*Cos[b] - Tan[c]*b];

gf = With[{slots = Slot /@ Range@Length@f[[1]]}, 
           Evaluate[Grad[Replace[f[[-1]], Thread[Rule[f[[1]], slots]], Infinity], slots]] &];

gf
gf[0, 2, 3] // N

(*

{Cos[#1] Cos[#2],-Sin[#1] Sin[#2]-Tan[#3],-Sec[#3]^2 #2}&

{-0.416147,0.142547,-2.04064}

*)
```

Comment: It does seem to work exactly as I want when we use the hash symbols to define f. It doesn't seem to like functions defined with Function[] and non hash symbols though. I can probably live with that but is it possible to include such functions as well?

Comment: @rr: Well, it was done for "anonymous" functions as posted ;-) Hang on a sec, I'll see what I can cobble up.

Comment: I guess I don't understand the difference. I thought the hash constructs were the same as using Function[].

Comment: @rr *Mathematica* and W/R tend to use the "Lispy" definition of it, no worries, updated.

Answer (score 3):

Based on your self answer it would seem that this will do what you want quite a bit more cleanly:

```
grad[func_, n_] := Function @@ {D[func[##], {{##}}]} & @@ Array[Slot, n]
```

Test:

```
f = Sin[#1]*Cos[#2] - Tan[#3]*#2 &;

grad[f, 3]
```

> ```
> {Cos[#1] Cos[#2], -Sin[#1] Sin[#2] - Tan[#3], -Sec[#3]^2 #2} &
> ```

Or looking at this operation again, also:

```
grad2[func_, n_] := Thread[Derivative[##][func] & @@@ IdentityMatrix[n], Function]
```

There is also [`Grad`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Grad.html) in versions 9 and later:

```
grad3[func_, n_] := Function @@ {Grad[func[##], {##}]} & @@ Array[Slot, n]
```

Comment: You have a typo in `grad2`: `f` should be `func`. (+1)

Comment: @Jens Thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a way of doing this that I like.

```
SlotN[n_] := Module[{i}, Table[Slot[i], {i, 1, n}]]
PureGradN[func_, n_] := Module[{i}, Evaluate[D[func @@ SlotN[n], {SlotN[n]}]] &]
```

This does exactly what I had in mind and works for explicit or anonymous/pure functions.